# New line character does not work with other parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, newline, console.log

I just basically started learning JS and stuck on this problem, thank you for your help.

I created an **array** which I refer to in **console.log** and everythink worked, until I wanted to add a **string with new line**.

Here's my code:

```
var array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,0]];
console.log(array[0], array.length, "hello \n world");
```

After I turn on the program, google console shows something like this:

> (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 2 'hello \n world'

And the " 'hello \n world' " is red if it matters.

I also tried with "+" instead of ",": but also didn't work, can anyone help? Why the "world" isn't in the second line?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,0]];
console.log("\("+array[0].length+"\)" + JSON.stringify(array[0]), array.length, "hello world");
```

It's working as expected, Please comment if you need something else in output.

[image: output]

Comment: Well, I was expecting smth more like this:

                                                                   
   (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 2 hello
 world

Comment: Okay, got you. please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Console log is meant as a debugger, not really for formatting/formatted text. I guess its approach is to try to show you what is being logged, not to render it in any way.

Out of curiosity why would you want to have a line break in your logged data?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's showing `hello \n world` in red. It only does this if it's not the first argument. If you do `console.log('hello \n world')` it splits it across 2 lines.

Comment: Values seem to be color coded by type.

Comment: Interesting that you get it in blue (or is that green?), but the OP and I get it in red.

Comment: Will prob depend on your browser/version/os/whoknows

Comment: I am just new to coding and wanted to try explore all possibilities of doing it to have better foundations when I will move on, even though some things may have no sense - pixelearth

Answer (score 0):

Try providing with formatting string and then values

```js
v1 = "foo";
v2 = "boo";
console.log("%s\n%s", v1, v2);
```